# Query - nested top 1 select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, that returns below -example- results

```sql
DECLARE @idArea AS integer = 61;
DECLARE @dataDa AS datetime = '20210629 00:00';
DECLARE @dataA AS datetime = '20210629 23:59';
DECLARE @idUtilizzatore AS integer = 0;
DECLARE @idAzienda AS integer = 0;

WITH area AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.CODICEBADGE,
        COGNOME AS Cognome,
        NOME AS Nome,
        AZIENDE.DESCR AS Azienda,
        FORMAT(DATAORA, 'HH:mm') AS Ora,
        FORMAT(dataora, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS Data,
        IIF(verso = 0, 'U', 'E') AS Flusso,
        t.IDTERMINALE,
        t.DATAORA
    FROM 
        timbaccessi t
    JOIN 
        badge ON badge.codice = t.codicebadge
    JOIN 
        anagrafico ON anagrafico.ID = badge.IDUTILIZZATORE
    JOIN 
        profilo ON profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE = badge.IDUTILIZZATORE
    JOIN 
        aziende ON AZIENDE.id = profilo.IDAZIENDA
    JOIN 
        terminali ON terminali.id = t.IDTERMINALE
    WHERE 
        (DATAORA >= @dataDa AND DATAORA < @dataA)
        AND (badge.DATAFINE IS NULL OR badge.DATAFINE >= @dataA)
        AND (badge.idUtilizzatore = @idUtilizzatore OR 0 = @idUtilizzatore)
        AND (profilo.IDAZIENDA = @idAzienda OR 0 = @idAzienda)
    GROUP BY 
        dataora, cognome, nome,
        t.CODICEBADGE, AZIENDE.DESCR, t.VERSO, t.IDTERMINALE
)
SELECT 
    s.Descr AS Lettore,
    a.CODICEBADGE,
    a.Cognome,
    a.Nome,
    a.Azienda,
    a.Ora,
    a.Data,
    a.Flusso
FROM
    area a
JOIN 
    dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree s ON s.id IN (@idArea)
WHERE
    a.IDTERMINALE IN (SELECT idterminale
                      FROM dbAree.dbo.termArea t
                      JOIN dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree s ON s.id = t.idArea
                      WHERE t.idArea IN (@idArea)
                        AND (@dataDa >= s.datada
                        AND (s.dataA IS NULL OR @dataDa < s.dataA)));
```

Output:

```
    Lettore         CODICEBADGE Cognome Nome        Azienda                 Ora     Data        Flusso
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000015384  MACCIO' FRANCESCO   C&C SHIPPING SOLUTIONS  09:54   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000015384  MACCIO' FRANCESCO   C&C SHIPPING SOLUTIONS  10:19   29/06/2021  U
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000013028  RUIU    STEFANO     C.S.W.                  07:12   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000013028  RUIU    STEFANO     C.S.W.                  09:57   29/06/2021  U
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000013028  RUIU    STEFANO     C.S.W.                  10:11   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000010032  BELLUC  ANDRES      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    07:01   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000010032  BELLUC  ANDRES      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    10:11   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    07:07   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    08:53   29/06/2021  U
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    09:17   29/06/2021  E
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    09:57   29/06/2021  U
    PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    10:13   29/06/2021  E
```

I want to filter records by person keeping only who have an 'E' as value of Flusso field as more recent record (more recent data and ora field values), so with the example above:

```
Lettore         CODICEBADGE Cognome Nome        Azienda                 Ora     Data        Flusso
PM 6 - GIN191   0000013028  RUIU    STEFANO     C.S.W.                  10:11   29/06/2021  E
PM 6 - GIN191   0000010032  BELLUC  ANDRES      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    10:11   29/06/2021  E
PM 6 - GIN191   0000003285  CASALE  NICOLA      CONSTRUCT SHIP WORLD    10:13   29/06/2021  E
```

**EDIT**

I probably did't explain myself well enough... my request needs a little more conditional behaviour, in the example above IF codicebadge 0000015384 (the first in the list) have no other U record of later hours:minutes I want it shown in the query result, otherwise no. In the example it has a U record at 10:19 (> E record at 9:54), so it doesn't must be encluded in the result at all. On the other hand 0000013028 must appear because it doesn't have a U record after 10:11

Comment: White space and line breaks are "magical" things; they make your unreadable code readable.

Comment: Couple of notes on the above. You have a `GROUP BY` in your CTE but no aggregation; that is always a sign of a flaw in the query. Also it appears that the query in the CTE is what is known as a "catch-all" query or "kitchen sink" query. I suggest having a read of [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: @Larnu sorry and thank you

Comment: Side notes: 1. Why do you separate data and ora instead of using a datetime column for the combined date and time? Separating them makes sense when one of the columns is nullable, otherwise it just makes sme queires harder to get straight. 2. With only one elemant in `IN`, you can just use `=` instead: `t.idArea = @idArea`. 3.  You should make your cross join explicit: `CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree WHERE id = @idArea) s`. Or is this supposed to be an inner join? Where then is the area ID in the area subquery you'd probably join on?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter records by person keeping only who have an 'E' as value of Flusso field as more recent record (more recent data and ora field values),

Assuming that a person is represented by `CODICEBADGE`, uou can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CODICEBADGE order by data desc ora desc)_as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where Flusso = 'E' and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: i probably did't explain myself well enough... my request needs a little more conditional behaviour, in the example above IF codicebadge 0000015384 (the first in the list) have no other U record of later hours:minutes I want it shown in the query result, otherwise no. In the example it has a U record at 10:19 (> E record at 9:54), so it doesn't must be encluded in the result at all. On the other hand 0000013028 must appear because it doesn't have a U record after 10:11

Answer (score 0):

Number each persons' rows with `ROW_NUMBER` giving the last row #1. Then only keep the rows numbered #1 that have flusso = 'E'.

```
WITH area AS
(
  ...
)
SELECT lettore, codicebadge, cognome, nome, azienda, ora, data, flusso
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      s.Descr AS Lettore,
      ...,
      a.Flusso,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by a.nome, a.cognome
                         order by a.data desc, a.ora desc) AS rn
  FROM
      area a
  JOIN 
      dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree s ON s.id IN (@idArea)
  WHERE
      a.IDTERMINALE IN (SELECT idterminale
                        FROM dbAree.dbo.termArea t
                        JOIN dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree s ON s.id = t.idArea
                        WHERE t.idArea IN (@idArea)
                          AND (@dataDa >= s.datada
                          AND (s.dataA IS NULL OR @dataDa < s.dataA)))
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1 AND flusso = 'E';
```

Comment: i probably did't explain myself well enough... my request needs a little more conditional behaviour, in the example above IF codicebadge 0000015384 (the first in the list) have no other U record of later hours:minutes I want it shown in the query result, otherwise no. In the example it has a U record at 10:19 (> E record at 9:54), so it doesn't must be encluded in the result at all. On the other hand 0000013028 must appear because it doesn't have a U record after 10:11

Comment: Isn't this exactly how Gordon's and my query work? They look for a person's last row and only show it if it is 'E'. I don't see how this is different from your explanation.

Comment: your're right I didn't pay attention to the area id of the record